# How can I filter a string to extract the text after a symbol?

Tags: php, regex, function, hash

I have a function which can filter the text from a hashtag

```
function gethashtags($text)
        {
          //Match the hashtags
          preg_match_all('/(^|[^a-z0-9_])#([a-z0-9_]+)/i', $text, $matchedHashtags);
          $hashtag = '';
          // For each hashtag, strip all characters but alpha numeric
          if(!empty($matchedHashtags[0])) {
              foreach($matchedHashtags[0] as $match) {
                  $hashtag .= preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9]+/i", "", $match).',';
              }
          }
            //to remove last comma in a string
        return rtrim($hashtag, ',');
        }
```

So in my post file, the variable uses gethashtags() to extract the text but only if the string has a #. # being the trigger.

All I need is a similar function but uses @ as the trigger rather than a hash.

What function can achieve this result? I do not understand Regex's the slightest so I'm very sorry if this question comes across as vague as I've given my best effort to explain my problem.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Input and an expected output would be better.

Comment: The input is a form of which anything can be entered. For example, the input could be "Hello everyone" so the functions would ignore this but the input could also be "@Callum Hello! #hashtag" so the function would have to extract two pieces of text (Callum and Hashtag) so that they can be stored into the database

Comment: you mean this http://regex101.com/r/gD2oI8/1

Comment: Could you help me place this into a function similar to the above? and I just need the `^.*?@(\S+).*$` part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simplify your function like this:

```
function gethashtags($text) {
   preg_match_all('/\B[@#]\K\w+/', $text, $matches);
   return implode(',', $matches[0]);
}
echo gethashtags("@Callum Hello! #hashtag @another #hashtag");
```

**Explanation**:

- The `(^|[^a-z0-9_])` part of your regex works like a non-word boundary `\B`.
- Then we match either a `@` or `#` character. `\K` throws away everything that it has matched up to that point.
- Then we simply match word characters that follow either character and simply implode the results.

**Output**

```
Callum,hashtag,another,hashtag
```

Comment: Love this! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest `/([@#][^@^#]\S*)/g` to fetch all @.. and #..

http://regex101.com/r/gD2oI8/2

With `$sMatch{0}` you can check for @ or #
Or move the "(" behind the "[]" to skip it :-)